# Given the sequence $\{x_n\}$, prove $\{x_{2n}\}$ and $\{x_{2n-1}\}$ converge to the same limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive numbers with limit 0. I define a new sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
    x_1 &= a_1 \\
    \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, x_{n+1} &= x_n + (-1)^{n}a_{n+1}
\end{align*}
I have to prove that $\{x_{2n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{x_{2n-1}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are both convergent to the same limit $L$.

I have tried writing out the first few terms of the sequence:
\begin{align*}
    x_1 &= a_1 \\
x_2 &= a_1 - a_2 \\
x_3 &= a_1 - a_2 + a_3 \\
x_4 &= a_1 -a_2 + a_3 - a_4
\end{align*}
So $x_{2n} = x_{2n-1} - a_{2n}$. But I am stuck where to proceed from here. How should I show that $\{x_{2n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{x_{2n-1}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are both convergent to the same limit using the provided fact that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has limit 0 and decreasing?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have edited the question so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use the fact that $x_{2n}=x_{2n-1}-a_{2n}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n-1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}\,,$$

and use that to show that **if** either of the sequences $\langle x_{2n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ and $\langle x_{2n-1}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges, then both converge to the same limit.

The alternating series test tells you that $\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n+1}a_n$ converges, and $x_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum of this series, so ... ?

Comment: Sir, I haven't learned series test yet. Is there any that I can show this with Monotone Convergence Theorem? Is there any way I can show that $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$ is decreasing and bounded below, and conclude they are convergent by the theorem?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01: Yes, you can show that $$x_1>x_3>x_5>\ldots> x_6>x_4>x_2\,.$$

Comment: would you show this by induction? I've been trying to show this for 4 hours to no avail.. It geometrically makes sense, but I cannot formalize into rigorous proof.

Comment: @abrakadabra_01: Induction will work. Look at $x_{2n+2}-x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}-x_{2n-3}$. and remember that the $a_n$s are decreasing.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you mean by looking at $x_{2n+2} - x_{2n}$?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01: What is it in terms of the $a_k$s?

Comment: So I can show $x_{2n+2} - x_{2n} = a_{2n+1} - a_{2n+2} > 0$ by induction so $x_{2n+2} > x_{2n}$ and therefore $x_{2n}$ is increasing. But how do I show that it is bounded as well in order to show that it is convergent? Do I have to do another induction?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01: Show that the odd-numbered terms are decreasing, and use the fact that $x_{2n}<x_{2n-1}$ to show that $x_{2n}<x_1$ for each $n$.

Comment: @Brain M. Scott: could you check up my new question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048371/prove-the-sequence-x-2n-has-an-upper-bound and see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First show that $x_{2n}$ has a limit. You can do so by observing that through telescoping: $x_{2n}-x_1 = \sum_{k=2}^{2n}(-1)^ka_k$. The right side converges by Dirichlet's test. Now use $x_{2n}-a_{2n}=x_{2n-1}$ consider the limit of the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the limit of $\{x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}\}$. If $\{x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}\} \to 0$ and $\{x_{2n}\}$,$\{x_{2n+1}\}$ are both convergent, then you can conclude they have the same limit. You can use Monotone Convergence to prove $\{x_{2n}\}$ and $\{x_{2n+1}\}$ are convergent.

Comment: How would you show the limit of $\{x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}\}$ both converge to 0?

Comment: Write out the terms of the sequence $\{x_{2n+1} - x_{2n}\}$. Then you will be able to see why this sequence converges to 0.

Note, this only proves $\{x_{2n+1}\}$ and $\{x_{2n}\}$ have the same limit if $\{x_{2n+1}\}$ and $\{x_{2n}\}$ are known to be convergent (which is something you must prove).

Comment: How would you prove both subsequences are convergent? Would you use induction to show that they are monotonic and bounded?

Comment: Using the fact that the $a_n$ are positive and decreasing, you can show $\{x_{2n}\}$ is increasing and $\{x_{2n+1}\}$ is decreasing. Moreover, $\{x_{2n}\}$ is bounded above by $a_1$ and  $\{x_{2n+1}\}$ is bounded below by 0.